# Problems trying to compress files to ZIP in PHP

Tags: php, zip

I have a code where i'm trying to compress multiple files into a zip. This with help off PHP and MySQL 'cause, i have the links saved on a MySQL table. The problem is that the zip file is not created. This is the code:

```
<?php 


mysql_select_db("assignments",$conectar);  
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pedimento"); 

<?php 

$enzipado = new ZipArchive(); 
if ($enzipado->open("activos.zip", ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE )!==TRUE) { 
    exit("No se pudo abrir el archivo\n"); 
} 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
$enzipado->addFile($row['DepAduanero']); 
    }; 
$enzipado->close(); 
?> 
<a href="activos.zip">Descargar</a>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error and/or seeing your exit status message? Also, are you sure that you have file write permissions in the directory in which you're trying to create activos.zip?

Comment: How do you know that zip is not created? If you just have not working link - that may be a problem with a path where zip is located. If no - take a look at $enzipado->status and see what it means [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php#108601)

Comment: No, this don't get any error, and the zip is not created because it doesn't appear in the folder.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method ZipArchive::status() in E:\wamp\www\clientes\consulte\assignments\descargar.php on line 23

Answer (score 0):

It's always recommended to check if your files exists, before you put use them.
So use file_exists()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Or maybe your query just isn't returning any rows o.O

Comment: It says that the file exists. The file that i'm trying to compress, of course. Not the Zip

Comment: maybe check in your phpinfo() output whether the ZIP extension has been installed or not.

Comment: Yes: zip

Zip enabled
Extension Version $Id: php_zip.c,v 1.1.2.38.2.29 2009/02/24 23:55:14 iliaa Exp $
Zip version 1.9.1
Libzip version 0.9.0

Comment: Another possibility is that $enzipado->close(); returns false.
Check if thats the case.

Comment: if($enzipado->close()) {
   echo 'created!';
} else {
   echo 'failed';
}